# JDBC freezes after multiple query entries

Tags: java, jdbc

When i enter a correct username/password time the query work fine and the connection from client to server work as it should. However if I do an incorrect combination of username/password, then a correct one the program freezes. Im using java using a JDBC connection.

```
String usr = clientName.getText();
            String pass = clientPass.getText();
            String u = null, p = null;

            ResultSet results=null; 

            String stmtLogin = "Select * from userInfo where username = '" + usr + "'";

            try
            {           
                results = statement.executeQuery(stmtLogin);

                results.next();         
                    u = results.getString(1);
                    p = results.getString(2);           


            } 
            catch (SQLException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if ((pass.equals(p)) && usr.equals(u))

            {
                message = clientName.getText();
                output.println(message);            



                btnSendM.setEnabled(true);
                btnConn.setEnabled(false);  
                clientName.setEditable(false);
                clientPass.setEditable(false);

                messageBox.append(message + " has entered the chatroom \n");
                btnSendM.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 10));
                updateConnList();
            }
            else
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Username Password Incorrect, Please try Again");
```

Comment: did you try to use a debugger?

Comment: Are you ever closing any of these things? `ResultSet?` `Statement?` `Connection?`

Comment: no i'm not closing them here, ill try to close them and see if that  helps. Thanks

Comment: @EJP hi, ive tried closing the them, and it's still still freezing. The statement run everything a button is pressed, if that helps anyway

Comment: If this is running in an ActionListener that will freeze the GUI. You're not supposed to execute blocking operations on the event thread. Start a separate thread. And you're doing this wrong. You should do `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM userInfo WHERE USERNAME = ? AND PASSWORD = ?` and just see if you got a non-zero answer. You don't need to retrieve the password and compare it yourself: indeed if the password is hashed at the database, as it should be, you can't do that at all.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the same as your, but this is my login for one of my applications.

Your problem is probably that you doesn't close `connection` after you are done.

```
 try {
                String dbName = "ServerSQLite.db";
                connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + "serverDatabase/" + dbName);
                Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
                statement.setQueryTimeout(20);  // set timeout to 20 sec.

                ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("select * from registratedClients WHERE clientLogin = " + "\'" + loginName + "\'" +"and clientPassword = " + "\'" + password + "\'");
               //Do stuff with resultset
                rs.close();


            } catch (Exception e) {
                // if the error message is "out of memory",
                // it probably means no database file is found
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (connection != null)
                        connection.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    // connection close failed.
                    System.err.println(e);
                }
            }
```

Comment: i know get a url cannot be null excpetion